# How to implement Gilt.com like size selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, yui

I'm working on a E-commerce website. I want to implement size selection similar to how it's implemented in Gilt.com. Is there any jQuery plugin or a JS reference to do something like this?

[image: Gilt.com size selection implementation]